# Pyqt5 updated Widget is not added to the layout though the widget is updated

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to show set of actions when a button is clicked and other set of options if another button is clicked.
Below is the code:

```
  class Screen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Screen, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.all_running()
        layout.addWidget(self.running_full_widget)
        self.actions('1')
        layout.addWidget(self.actions_full_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()
    def all_running(self):
        self.running_full_widget = QWidget()
        runnning_full_layout= QVBoxLayout()
        button1 = QPushButton("btn1")
        button2 = QPushButton("btn2")
        button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.actions('2'))
        button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.actions('3'))
        runnning_full_layout.addWidget(button1)
        runnning_full_layout.addWidget(button2)
        self.running_full_widget.setLayout(runnning_full_layout)
    def actions(self,value):
        self.actions_full_widget= QWidget()
        val = int(value)
        print(val)
        actions_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        for i in range(val):
           actions_item = QLabel(str(i))
           actions_layout.addWidget(actions_item)
        self.actions_full_widget.setLayout(actions_layout)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
Gui = Screen()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When button is clicked i can see the value is updated but it is not updated in the main layout. 
how can i dynamically update the widgets ?
How can I do that in cases where i need to add widgets based on a dynamic value.
did i miss anything with signals and slots?
Kindly correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was almost there.  The problem you are seeing is the widgets were being added but never removed.  The following code could be simplified, but I tried to keep it close to yours so you could see the changes more easily.

The main change is now there is a class member `screen_layout` and the widgets are added/removed from it inside `actions()`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QApplication

class Screen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Screen, self).__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.screen_layout = layout
        self.all_running()
        layout.addWidget(self.running_full_widget)
        self.actions_full_widget = None
        self.actions('1')
        # layout.addWidget(self.actions_full_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()
    def all_running(self):
        self.running_full_widget = QWidget()
        runnning_full_layout= QVBoxLayout()
        button1 = QPushButton("btn1")
        button2 = QPushButton("btn2")
        button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.actions('2'))
        button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.actions('3'))
        runnning_full_layout.addWidget(button1)
        runnning_full_layout.addWidget(button2)
        self.running_full_widget.setLayout(runnning_full_layout)
    def actions(self,value):
        # Remove any previously added widget
        if self.actions_full_widget is not None:
            self.screen_layout.removeWidget(self.actions_full_widget)
            self.actions_full_widget.deleteLater()
        self.actions_full_widget= QWidget()
        val = int(value)
        print(val)
        actions_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        for i in range(val):
           actions_item = QLabel(str(i))
           actions_layout.addWidget(actions_item)
        self.actions_full_widget.setLayout(actions_layout)
        self.screen_layout.addWidget(self.actions_full_widget)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
Gui = Screen()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah it is working when I deleted the previous layout.

Comment: I am trying to make dynamic widgets that are clickable. Everything works but the problem is all the dynamic widgets are pointing to the last widget. I tried using sender and other methods . How can we work around that??          Below Im posting the code in the answer.

Comment: You're asking another question about some different code.  That should really be in another post.  It is definitely not the "answer" to the originally posted question.

Comment: Sorry for that I added additional things to the existing code. I will post it as another question.

Comment: I have posted as a different question below is the [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696362/pyqt5-making-dynamic-widgets-clickable-and-pass-arguments-to-another-function) 
kindly suggest me any possible solution. Sorry again