# PyQt5 making dynamic widgets clickable and pass arguments to another function

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to make dynamic widgets and make them clickable. By clicking on one widget it should pass dynamic value to other widget. I have tried sender() and other options accessing the widget but nothing worked. 
All the widgets are sending information from the last widget.

Below is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QMessageBox,QSizePolicy, QLayoutItem,QFrame,QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication,QSize,QFileInfo
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import sip 


class Screen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):

        super(Screen, self).__init__()

        self.running_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.action_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.running_layout)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.action_layout)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()
        self.all_running()        
        self.actions_1('1')
    def buttonClicked(self):      
        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender + ' was pressed')

    def all_running(self):
        for i in range(5):
            button = QLabel("btn "+str(i))
            button.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda _ : self.actions_1(str(button.text()).split()[1])
            self.running_layout.addWidget(button)


        button2 = QLabel("btn 5")
        button2.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda _ : self.actions_1(str(button2.text()).split()[1])        
        self.running_layout.addWidget(button2)


    def actions_1(self,value):

        while not self.action_layout.isEmpty():
            print(self.action_layout.isEmpty())
            widget = self.action_layout.itemAt(0).widget()
            print("removing", widget)
            widget.setVisible(False)
            self.action_layout.removeWidget(widget)
            del widget
        self.action_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(self.action_layout)
        val = int(value)

        for i in range(val):
            actions_item = QLabel(str(i))
            self.action_layout.addWidget(actions_item)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
Gui = Screen()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edited:** I am trying to pass an int to actions based on the int value that number of widgets need to get populate. 
This int is based on the dynamic widget which i generated using the for loop. 
For example if the first widget of running_layout "btn 0" is clicked there won't be any widgets in the action_layout, If the second widget of running_layout "btn 1" is clicked there will be one widget "0" in the action_layout and so on based on the widget number. 
I am able to send the signal but on whichever dynamically created widget i click it is sending value 4 of last widget "btn 4" to the action_layout.

Comment: You could explain in detail what you want to do.

Comment: In short: if you press the widget btn i then in the other layout should appear i-widgets.

Comment: Exactly that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Try my solution and if I help you do not forget to mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify the task we will create 2 widgets, the first one will be `ClickableWidget` that will have a signal indicating the number associated with the widget, whereas the second `DynamicWidget` will have a method that will be in charge of updating the number of widgets.

To know if an element is pressed we use the method `installEventFilter()` and `eventFilter()`, this filters the events giving information of the object and event, we will use `setProperty("index", )` to store the number.

In the second widget I have implemented a method that is responsible for cleaning the widgets and creating some new widgets.

```
class ClickableWidget(QWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal(int)
    def  __init__(self, n=5, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.hlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        for i in range(n):
            label = QLabel("btn {}".format(i), self)
            label.setProperty("index", i)
            self.hlayout.addWidget(label)
            label.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if isinstance(obj, QLabel) and event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            i = obj.property("index") 
            self.clicked.emit(i)
        return QWidget.eventFilter(self, obj, event)

class DynamicWidget(QWidget):
    def  __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.hlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

    def changeWidget(self, n):
        def clearLayout(layout):
            item = layout.takeAt(0)
            while item:
                w = item.widget()
                if w:
                    w.deleteLater()
                lay = item.layout()
                if lay:
                    clearLayout(item.layout())
                item = layout.takeAt(0)

        clearLayout(self.hlayout)
        for i in range(n):
            label = QLabel("btn {}".format(i), self)
            self.hlayout.addWidget(label)


class Screen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Screen, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        c = ClickableWidget(6, self)
        d = DynamicWidget(self)
        c.clicked.connect(d.changeWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(c)
        self.layout.addWidget(d)
```

Comment: I recommend separating the tasks, wanting to do everything at once is problematic.

Comment: In what I am doing the variables of both widgets are dependent so I used a single class. Now I will just change it and use more classes. Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062681/pyqt5-addstretch-in-between-widgets